# Conditionally call ViewComponent inside Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to Razor Pages and View Components and I'm cleary failing to put my head around the concepts:

I have a `Example page`, this page is rendered inside a `_Layout`, like the following:

```
@page "{value1?}/{value2?}"
@model MyProject.Pages.ExampleModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Example";
}
```

Now I need to call a ViewComponent conditionally based on `value1` and `value2`:

```
public class ExampleModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string value1, string value2)
    {
        // this contains a lot of logic, db access etc, and passing objects to the component, but I'm abbreviating

        if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
        {
            return this.ViewComponent(nameof(SomeComponent));
        }
        else
        {
            return this.ViewComponent(nameof(SomeOtherComponent));
        }

        // return Page();
    }
}
```

This is the extension I'm using to call the components:

```
public static class PageModelExtensions
{
    public static ViewComponentResult ViewComponent(this PageModel pageModel, string componentName, object arguments)
    {
        return new ViewComponentResult
        {
            ViewComponentName = componentName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            ViewData = pageModel.ViewData,
            TempData = pageModel.TempData
        };
    }
}
```

This is working, but because I'm not calling `return Page()`, the component is being rendered without calling `_Layout`. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to render a View Component from within a Razor Page like this, one option is to specify the name of said View Component in your `PageModel` class and then use [`Component.InvokeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#invoking-a-view-component) in the correpsonding .cshtml file. Here's what that might look like:

Example.cshtml.cs

```
public class ExampleModel : PageModel
{
    public string ViewComponentName { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string value1, string value2)
    {
        ...

        if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
            ViewComponentName = nameof(SomeComponent);
        else
            ViewComponentName = nameof(SomeOtherComponent);

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Example.cshtml

```
@page "{value1?}/{value2?}"
@model MyProject.Pages.ExampleModel

...

@await Component.InvokeAsync(Model.ViewComponentName)
```

In Example.cshtml.cs, `ViewComponentName` is a new property that (unsurprisingly) represents the name of the View Component that should be rendered as part of the page, which is realised in Example.cshtml using `Component.InvokeAsync`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can see how to apply the same method using parameters `Component.InvokeAsync(Model.ViewComponentName, Model.SomeParameter)`. Is this right? Thx.

Comment: I want to use sameview component but two times with different parameters. So basically two instances in a sameview. How to do that?